# Retrieve Socket.io Client from Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, scale

I'm building a real time data system that allows an Apache/PHP server to send data to my Node.js server, which will then immediately send that data to the associated client via socket.io.  So the Apache/PHP server makes a request that includes the data, as well as a user token that tells Node.js which user to send the data to.

Right now this is working fine - I've got an associative array that ties the user's socket.io connection to their user token.  The problem is that I need to start scaling this to multiple servers.  Naturally, with the default configs of socket.io I can't share connections between node workers.

The solution I had in mind was to use the RedisStore functionality, and just have each of my workers looking at the same Redis store.  I've been doing research and there's a lot of documentation on how to use pub/sub functionality for broadcasting messages to large groups (rooms).  That's fine, but I need to be able to send messages to a single client, so I need some way to retrieve a user's socket.io connection from the RedisStore.

The only way I can think to do this right now is to create a ton of 'rooms' named with the user's token, and only have one user in each room.  Then I could just emit to that room.  However, that seems very inefficient.

Is there a better way that I can retrieve user's unique socket.io connections from Redis?

Comment: I don't see how adding more servers will change anything. Once a socket.io connection is established between the browser and the nodejs instance, it will stay on the same server for the life of that connection. Why would the other servers in the cluster need to know about this particular connection?

Comment: Well, that's the idea behind the RedisStore.  Redis will allow all of the servers to know about _and communicate with_ all the stored clients.

Comment: Checkout bus.io on npm.  It provides an express-like interface for building real-time distributed apps onto of redid and socket.io.  It solves the problem of managing socket.io clients.

Comment: You've said that `I've got an associative array that ties the user's socket.io connection to their user token` - how do you do that? How does the server know that this particular socket (socket.id = 12387) represent this particular token (token = 198237189237)?

Answer (score 0):

Once a socket connection is made to a server running the node server, it is connected to that instance.

So it seems you need to make a way for your php server to know which node server a client is connected to.

In your redis store you could just store the id of the server as the value by the client id. Then php looks up which node server to use and makes the request.